# React useState function not changing value when inside useEffect/Event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to create a piece of code that will mode a div when the user scrolls past a certain place. to do this i used `window.addEventListener('scroll', () => checkSection(scrollSection, setScrollSection))` where i pass both of the variables returned from `React.useState(0)`, then from within the event listener i check to see if the `window.scrollY` property is more than the value in the `scrollSection` state and if so translate it with js. but no matter what i do the function provided to update the state isnt updating the state, its not slow its just not updating at all. I was wondering if this is because i passed it into an event listener?

**Event Listener and useState Initialization**

```
function SideNav(props: any) {
  const [scrollSection, setScrollSection] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => checkSection(scrollSection, setScrollSection));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => checkSection(scrollSection, setScrollSection));
    };
  }, []);
```

**Function passed to event listener**

```
function checkSection(scrollSection: number, setScrollSection: Function){
  let scrollSections = [0, 1538, 2583, 2089, 3089]
  const scrollY = window.scrollY;
  setScrollSection(1);
  console.log("scroll Y: "+scrollY);
  console.log("section: "+scrollSection)
}
```

Comment: Two issues: 1. That isn't how you remove an event listener. You have to use the **same function**, not an equivalent function, in the call to `removeEventListener`. 2. Your event listener closes over the **first** version of `scrollSection`, not the updated version later calls to your component function see.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try to implement this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i got the code to add the event listener online and don't understand much about them including the correct way to remove one, would i accomplish this by first saving `() => checkSection(scrollSection, setScrollSection)` in a variable and passing that to the `window.addEventListener` and `window.closeEventListener`?

also I'm not sure how to fix the second problem you listed.

Comment: @DarcyPower - Do `const handler = () => checkSection(scrollSection, setScrollSection);`, then use `handler` both in the `addEventListener` call and the `removeEventListener` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is asynchronous. you will not see the updated value immediately after setting the value. use `useEffect` to catch the updated values

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("section: "+scrollSection)

}, [scrollSection])
```

Comment: Stale state is ***very*** well-covered by previous questions and answers. Better to find the earlier question than to post Yet Another Answer to the same question.